# Is it possible to install my own verison of Windows in AWS EC2 or lightsail

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-lightsail

I want to install my own version of Windows in AWS EC2 or Lightsail. Is this possible?
If yes, how do I install it? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Lightsail: no.

EC2: maybe, depending on what you mean by *installing* your own version of Windows. You can *import* a Windows image, as long as it's one of the [supported Windows variants](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmie_prereqs.html). You can't import your favorite Windows XP VM, for example.

You can also potentially [bring your own license (BYOL)](https://aws.amazon.com/windows/faq1/), if that's you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks. I just feel windows instance in AWS is more expensive and I have windows server licenses. So, I feel it should be cheaper to create a linux instance first and then install a windows server myself. Is this feasible?

Comment: If I bring my own license, do I pay the same price as if I use a AWS windows license?

Comment: I think your first question is asking if you can install Windows in a VM on a Linux EC2 instance. If so, no you can't run virtualization within virtualization on EC2. If you BYOL then the EC2 cost does not include the license cost (see https://aws.amazon.com/windows/faq/). But ... licensing is a complex area so be sure to read and fully understand the rules.

Comment: Thanks. I mean if I buy a linux instance, could I replace the linux with windows by installing windows myself? I don't mean running windows on top of linux. I just want to replace linux with windows.

Comment: You don't buy an instance. You rent it. When you launch an EC2 instance, you choose from a library of machine images (called AMIs). Each comes with an Operating System. If you want to switch from Linux to Windows, you terminate your Linux instance and you launch a new Windows instance.